# Aqua Regia 0.1M solution

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I was reading a method for total digestion, and the method uses 0.1 M aqua regia. I know that aqua regia has 3 parts Hcl and 1 part HNO3, by volume. How would I make a 0.1 M aqua regia solution, is the 0.1 M referring to the HCl or the HNO3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can be aqua regia 0.1 M, when it is mixture of concentrated acids? It is like having 0.4% whisky.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Aqua Regia 0.1M"

Comment: You need to consult the source what they mean.  A asking B what C means by X is bad concept, if X does not makes sense or is unclear without more details or context.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments imply, this isn't aqua regia at all. What makes something aqua regia is its content of molecules of nitric acid and whatever other stuff is produced when these molecules react with the hydrochloric acid. (Hydrochloric acid itself is stronger and may still be dissociated.) Put this stuff into enough water to make the concentration 0.1 molar, you dissociate those nitric avid molecules and hydrolyze the aqua Regia reaction products noted above, and all you're left with is dilute-acid ion soup.

"Aqua regia" is classically a 3:1 (respective) mixture of hydrochloric acid with nitric acid. I've never seen what that 3:1 is based on, probably it's by volume in which case the molar ratio is probably closer to 1:1. I would make 0.05 molar HCl and 0.05 molar HNO3 (labeling it like that, not an aqua regia solution) and call it a day.